# $m^*(E_j) = m^*(F_j) \implies m^*(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j) = m^*(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty F_j)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Define $m^*(E) = \inf \{m(U): U \text{ open and }E \subseteq U\},$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$.

Suppose $\{E_j\},\{F_j\} \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ are increasing sequences of sets satisfying $F_j$ is a $G_\delta$ set, $E_j \subseteq F_j$ and $m^*(E_j) = m(F_j)$ for all $j \in \mathbb N$. Here, a $G_\delta$ set is defined to be a countable intersection of open sets. I know that
$$m^*(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty  E_j) \leq m^*(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty  F_j)$$ by the monotonicity of $m^*$.
Is it also true that $$m^*(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty  E_j) \geq m^*(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty  F_j)?$$
I think this is true but am unsure of a proof.

Comment: As I recall: this is not true for all outer measures, but it is true for Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Since each $F_j$ is measurable,
$$
m^*\!\left(\bigcup_{j\ge 1}E_j \right)\ge \limsup_{k\to\infty}m^*(E_k)=\limsup_{k\to\infty}m(F_k)=m\!\left(\bigcup_{j\ge 1}F_j \right).
$$

Comment: Can you explain how you obtain the first inequality?

Comment: Each $E_k\subseteq \bigcup_{j\ge 1} E_j$ and so $m^*\!\left(\bigcup_{j\ge 1}E_j \right)\ge m^*(E_k)$.